# use chrome extension to open tab *virtually*

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am creating an automated tool to manage tabs, a Chrome Extension. I need to make sure a tab is fully loaded and data saved (for example a chat gpt question where the answer is still loading etc).

Is there an API call with chrome extensions where I can "open" a page virtually but not actually bring it to the foreground?

AKA, I want to open in background but not actually steal the view from the human user.

Something like:

```
  chrome.tabs.update(existingTab.id, { selected: false, virtualSelected: true });
```

Comment: The closest thing is the offscreen document API where you can either directly process DOM or add an iframe to a site and process it using a content script with all_frames, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76268724).

Comment: ok thanks, can you add that as an answer? will upvote

Comment: If that answer covers the use case and you can add an example of your implementation there then I think it'd make more sense close this one as a duplicate.